# How to split a memory consuming computation into parts and then save and load each parts?

Tags: python

I wrote this Python 3 code to bench mark some computation.

unfortunately it crashes my 30GB memory when n is equal or greater than 3.

```
def benchmking(n=0):
    import time
    items = range(int(10**(6+n)))
    def f2(x):return x*x

    start = time.time()
    squared = list(map(f2, items))
    return time.time() - start
```

I admit that this code is memory consuming.

One possible solution I can imagine is split the computation and save the results into file system, but how?

## question

I was trying to benchmark a big computation both with regular and parallel approaches. Now I am trying to save the intermediate computation.

Comment: `list(map(f2, items))` -- that's going to consume `O(10^n)` memory.. :}

Comment: Do you have to store the result as a list that you never use anyway?

Comment: Do you have to set your turn your map into a list? You could leave it as a generator.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to benchmark?

Comment: @Loocid The calculations will not be performed if it is left as a generator though.

Comment: @Loocid don't have to be a list, any other format is good.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to measure the time required to calculate squares, or do you need the results (squared numbers) too? If not, why do you store them in _any_ format?

Comment: @Selcuk I updated. The goal is to bench mark. I use list is to have the computation execute rather than a lazy op.

Comment: @Selcuk I was trying to benchmark a regular big computation and parallel computation. Now I am trying to save the intermediate computation.

Comment: @singularli you could force the thunk by doing `squared = map(f2, items); for _ in squared: pass` which doesn't try to create a list in memory the length of `items`

Answer (score 1):

You can produce the squares using a generator, holding each one in memory for only a short time.

```
def benchmaking(n=0):
    squares = (x*x for x in range(int(10**(6+n)))
```

but if you want the whole list in memory, then clearly you need enough memory to store the whole list....

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it won't calculate all the squares unless you iterate the whole iterator, i.e. it won't be a real benchmark.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I stand corrected, sorry for misreading your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it as I am on mobile but worth a try. My solution is on the line of your thought where you wanted to save each result to the disk. Please note that if my method will work, it will produce a lot of files.

```py
import time
import numpy as np
def benchmking(n=0):
    for x in range(int(10**(6+n))):
        Filename = str(x)+'.npy'
        Filevalue = np.array([x*x])
        np.save(Filename, Filevalue)

start = time.time()
squared = benchmarking(4)
TimeTaken= time.time() - start
print(TimeTaken)
```

I am sorry if this is not what you wanted.